# Load multiple CSV's into MySQL using shell script

Tags: mysql, shell, csv

Inside a directory /mylog/ I have a bunch of CSV files. Each CSV file only has one line of data. I need this data to be inputted into a MySQL Database.

An example of a line would be:

```
2015-08-14 00:00:00,HOSTNAME,10271kB,17182kB,92874kB,10%,/dev/disk1,/
```

I need to remove the 'kB' from each file size and remove the % from the percentage field. I also need to make sure that the date time and hostname are always unique and no duplicate entries are ever put in.

This is what I started to write so far. But I'm obviously missing the database name to use and removing the kB and %. If there's anything else wrong or missing, let me know. There's also the fact mysql is called each time, is there a way to do multiple load data?

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in /var/log/mylog/*.csv
do
mysql -e "load data local infile '"$f"' into table myTable fields TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"  -u myUser --password=myPassword --local-infile
done
```

Comment: It is safer to process individually since there will be csv files being rsync'd multiple times per day to this folder.

Comment: I agree that you should combine all into one file. I'd recommend `mv` ing files to a `Processed` directory after you have processed each "batch". Else your description in your question is NOT clear enough about the scope of your project. Good luck.

Comment: I want to keep the files for a period of 14 days. I was thinking marking them with .complete or .done instead of moving to another folder.